# why centos 7.x veth pair ping fail each other

Tags: centos, ping

```bash
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
ip addr add 192.168.3.101/24 dev veth0
ip addr add 192.168.3.102/24 dev veth1
ip link set veth0 up
ip link set veth1 up

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/veth1/accept_local
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/veth0/accept_local
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/veth0/rp_filter
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/veth1/rp_filter

ping -c 1 -I veth0 192.168.3.102
```

I have tried on ubuntu / centos / fedora, why only centos 7.x ping fail?

At first I thought it was caused by the kernel version, but now it seems that this is not the case

Details are as follows:

- ubuntu 14.04.6 kernel 4.4.0 ping success
- ubuntu 13.10 kernel 3.11.0 ping success
- ubuntu 12.10 kernel 3.5.0 ping success
- centos 7.8 kernel 3.10.0 ping fail
- centos 7.9 kernel 3.10.0 ping fail
- centos 8.5 kernel 4.18.0 ping success
- fedora 21 kernel 3.17.4 ping success